# Warranty and status of M1 macbook air

Tags: macbook, warranty

I bought my M1 macbook air 2 days, i tried to check the status
when i checked its status at apple's website it says purchase date not validated and the picture there shows a rose gold mac but i bought a space grey variant is something wrong here ?
do i have to update the purchase date i think it should be done by the apple reseller i bought this device from right?
PS it was a physical store not a online one

Comment: [Error of Purchase Date not Validated](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251273092#:~:text=%22If%20your%20coverage%20expiration%20date%20is%20incorrect&text=You%20will%20need%20to%20send,a%20valid%20proof%20of%20purchase) I'm not sure about the picture on the site vs what the actual device is. That could be an error on their site. The color of the device is represented in the later digits of the serial number.

Comment: what digits are you talking about ?

Comment: Take it back to the shop and ask them to validate the purchase date.

Comment: @DavidPostill they say that sometimes it happens and you can talk to apple support and upload you bill invoice there is this right as i think its not my job to do that and should i insist the store to do it for me ?