# macbook new or old?

Tags: battery, macbook

i bought a new m1 macbook air few days ago and i wanted to know what should be the battery cycle count in a new machine and if its normal to have 2 battery cycle counts in a new macbook? i mean shouldn't it be zero?

Comment: Dupe of  [Back date installations in m1 macbook](https://superuser.com/questions/1624154/back-date-installations-in-m1-macbook)

Comment: Same as last time you asked - Somebody has to set up every Mac & test it before it's boxed & shipped. What else would you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Simple explanation for a cycle count of 2 on a new Mac.

1. Someone cycled the battery to test it before it ever went in the computer.
2. Someone cycled it once more once it was in the computer.

Both of these are part of the installation tests to ensure you get a working computer.

A cycle count of zero would indicate the company you bought it from had no quality control at all.

Comment: ohh ok and yea some people got 6 cycle counts is that also normal?

Comment: I'm not sure how many different ways i can answer this. Yes. You can expect **some** cycle counts. If the first build had an issue & parts were replaced, or the testing needed more than a couple of runs before it passed. You seem to be expecting a new car to have zero miles after it's been delivered to your door.

Comment: thank you so much and yea also is the space bar generally a bit loose than other keys and yea if the first build was not defective i would still get some counts right? i may sound too insecure because buying a mac was not a one day decision for me and thanks for cooperating knowing the fact that i am getting super annoying :)

Comment: can you please answer this question as i trust you a lot https://superuser.com/questions/1624104/warranty-and-status-of-m1-macbook-air

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/348261/new-macbook-pro-has-a-battery-cycle-count-of-2 kindly check the comment by allen i guess he is wrong

Comment: I think you need to put your paranoia away now. I just cannot respond any further to this line of enquiry, sorry. 2 cycles is a **brand new Mac!**

Comment: okay thank you so much i got it and you have been really helpful and can you please respond to that question in the link?